# No results returned and no error after filtering data

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, group-by

I am trying to get the count of the most popular hashtag posts from twitter with the following query:

```
SELECT UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(text, ' ')) AS word, 
       COUNT(*) AS word_count
FROM full_data
WHERE full_data.text = '#%'
GROUP BY word 
ORDER BY word_count DESC NULLS LAST 
LIMIT  1000;
```

However the results return nothing and I am not receiving an error, when I remove the WHERE clause the results return fine so I believe I may be making a mistake there.

here is what the data looks like [image]

I am expecting the following output except I'm only looking for results with '#' symbol

[image]

Comment: Update your post with sample input data and expected output tables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use

```
WHERE full_data.text LIKE '#%'
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this did not work and the output contained the same values as without filtering at all